# Hide Field with 'No Values' in the Attribute Dynamic Expression

Tags: arcmap, dynamic-text

Is there any way to hide an empty field in the 'Attribute Dynamic Text'?

Basically, I need to hide a the field name from the DDP if the field has no values.  The screenshot below shows the issue as I need to keep ID field (has values) but need to hide Street as has no values.

[image]

Please let me know if this is possible in HTML?

Comment: Please add more detail, what _exactly_ is your screen shot showing? To me its just some text labels?

Comment: Hi @Hornbydd. The screenshot shows an Attribute Dynamic text that changes based on the Data Driven Pages. If I move to next page the ID and Street values will change in the map. The issue is that I want to hide Street when there's 'NO VALUES' as it's irrelevant to show. Here is the HTML text feeding into the Dynamic text: 

ID: <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="ownershipr" domainlookup="true"/>

Street: <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="occupier" domainlookup="true" empty=" "/>

How Can I tell ArcMap not to show Street when shows ‘NO VALUES’? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want but only by running the Data Driven Pages (DDP) through a simple script.  You cannot do what you want through the UI.

Before you do anything you need to give the text element a name. So in your street example, right click select properties and set *Element Name* as shown below. I've called mine simply *street*.

[image: Properties]

You can then run the following script in the python command window, tweak as needed then simple copy and paste it into the python window and press enter. In this example I'm exporting to a PNG.

```py
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

# Get position of text element
ele = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "street")[0]
pos =  ele.elementPositionX

# Run loop for DDP
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum  # Sets current page
    aRow = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow           # Gets the row
    fieldValue = aRow.getValue("DESCRIPTION")    # Get the value from the field, in this example I use a field called DESCRIPTION
    if fieldValue == "" or fieldValue is None:
        # Shift the text element off layout
        ele.elementPositionX = ele.elementPositionX + 1000000
    else:
        # Put element back on layout
        ele.elementPositionX = pos

    # Do the export
    print("Exporting " + str(pageNum))
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"C:\Scratch\Tes_Page" + str(pageNum) + ".png")

# Finally ensure element is back of page
ele.elementPositionX = pos
```